# Meaning of 'get caught -ing

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm going to **get caught singing to this cat.**

Is this sentence means I'm going to be hooked on singing to cats? Or Someone else will see me singing to the cat?
Or is it means something completely different?

Comment: Your text ***could*** mean any of several different things, depending on the context. But your suggested "get hooked on singing to cats" sounds like a ridiculously unlikely interpretation to me. With no context, this is a fairly meaningless question anyway, but ***my*** default reading (of a context that seems to make sense) is that the speaker is hiding from someone, and realises that if he continues singing to the cat, whoever's looking for him will hear the singing (enabling him  to find / catch the speaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get caught" doing something means that someone will see you doing it.

This is commonly used to refer to someone who is seen committing a crime, or otherwise discovered to be guilty. Like, "He was caught stealing".

It's often used to refer to being seen doing something embarrassing but not illegal. Probably as an analogy to being seen committing a crime, though I haven't studied the history of it. Like, "His wife caught him watching porn". Or in this case, presumably the writer thinks that being seen singing to his cat will make him look foolish.

Note that we use the same phrase for being seen doing something really awful as for things that are just mildly embarrassing. Like you could say, "He was caught molesting a 6 year old", but it's also perfectly normal to say, "He was caught watching a soap opera."

Comment: To be taken by surprise, because of a lack of attention, can be to be 'caught napping'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, good point. Note "napping" here is figurative. Like, "When the Japanese attacked Pearl Harbor, the US military was caught napping." Not that they were literally asleep, but unprepared.